# Ubuntu how to remove stored authentications for filemanager-connections

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, server, file-manager

I'm wondering where ubuntu store the connection data for ftp-connections. I saved some logins which I have to remove now but I don't know the location where they are stored at. Can anyone help me cause I need to remove Passwords .

EDIT: I'm using nautilus

Answer (score 0):

Found it after hours....

for all whos searching too: 
~/.config/nautilus/servers